# Cant find namespace in Visual Studio 2017 RC

Tags: c#, visual-studio, namespaces, visual-studio-2017

I am actually working on an Outlook VSTO-Add In in VS 2017 RC and tried to access the namespace System.Security.Cryptography.Pkcs (https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/system.security.cryptography.pkcs(v=vs.110).aspx), sadly VS says, that this namespace could not be found - I am quite new to Visual Studio, am I doing something wrong when trying to access this namespace?

```
using System.Security.Cryptography.Pkcs.SignedCms;
```

Comment: Right click on the project, choose *Add reference* search for *System.Security* i'm pretty sure it is in an assembly which you are not referencing to

Comment: worked for me, tank you :)

Comment: Whenever you want to use a particular class, check that classes [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/system.security.cryptography.pkcs.signedcms(v=vs.110).aspx). There are two lines at the top of most pages, telling you which namespace it's in and which *assembly* it's in.